# Why is my hashmap only taking the last entry?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hashmap

I'm running a native query using Hibernate JPA and returning a results list.

The results list I want to take and add into a map for future processing, however the returned map only contains the last item from the ResultList.

How can I have the results list add multiple entries in the map?

```
Map<String,String> results = new HashMap<>();

Query query = em.createNativeQuery(select);
List<Object[]> resultSet = query.getResultList();

for(Object[] o : resultSet){
    System.out.println(o[0] + "\t"+ o[1]); //this prints out the columns correctly
    results.put((String)o[0],(String)o[1]); //but this only ever holds the last displayed column
}
```

--Edit--

**expected map contents:**

940    7107877 
 940    7107664 
 940    7112778 
 940    7112479 
 940    7114678 
 940    7113504

**println output**

940    7107877 
 940    7107664 
 940    7112778 
 940    7112479 
 940    7114678 
 940    7113504

**debugger output**

From the image below you can see that results size = 1, a sample of the result set showing objects, and the i counter (which I added to illustrate which iteration I'm on)

[image]

Comment: What is the output from the `println` line?

Comment: The correct output, which is why I'm real confused.

Comment: Your (String)o[0] is probably equating to the same value each time, so only the last one is stored

Comment: Please add the output to your question.

Comment: I'll update with some debugging info - allow me a few moments...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `o[0]` is always the same each time, then you will keep overwriting the previous value since Map by definition has one value per key. You should either use a List (containing some custom object that holds both values) or use something like [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from the Google Collections library, which allows you to `put` the same key multiple times, and `get` returns a collection of values.

Comment: I would agree with you if the println output was the same each time, but it's not.

Comment: It is - in your example the key you use is "940" for every result.

Comment: No worries, we all need a second pair of eyes sometimes.